# Bouncy castle no such method error

Tags: encryption, bouncycastle

I'm trying to decrypt a file using Bouncy Castle v1.53 PGP and Using PGPUtil class.
The program works fine in my Eclipse, but given following error when integrated inside a war file and deployed onto a weblogic server.I'm using following dependencies: 
    1)bcpg-jdk15on
    2)bcprov-jdk15on

**Error**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:   
 org.bouncycastle.util.Strings.newList()Lorg/bouncycastle/util/StringList;
 at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.ArmoredInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.bcpg.ArmoredInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(Unknown Source)`
```

**Resolution**

This problem is resolved when I copied following classes into my source folder:

```
org.bouncycastle.util.Strings  
org.bouncycastle.util.StringList  
org.bouncycastle.bcpg.ArmoredInputStream  
org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil`
```

by changing their Class Names

**However, I want a better fix than this as I feel this is some Jar Conflict
Please let me know if anyone finds one**

Comment: Please provide some code...

Comment: `boolean hasHeaders = true;
String header = null;
boolean newLineFound = false;
boolean clearText = false;
boolean restart = false;
StringList headerList= Strings.newList();//error
int lastC = 0;
boolean isEndOfStream;
private boolean parseHeaders()
throws IOException
{
header = null;
int c;
int last = 0;
boolean headerFound = false;
headerList = Strings.newList();//error
if (restart)
{
headerFound = true;
}
else
{
while ((c = in.read()) >= 0)
{
if (c == '-' && (last == 0 || last == '\n' || last == '\r'))
{
headerFound = true;
break;
}
last = c;
}
}`

Comment: This code is inside ArmoredInputStream class.Also Strings and StringList both classes are part of Bouncy Castle's dependencies

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code with appropriate formatting. Also, why are you copying classes? You should include the bouncycastle jar in your classpath and import the missing classes.

Answer (score 3):

That error is likely happening because you are using one version of the bouncycastle .jars when you run with Eclipse, but there is a different version of one of those .jars which is on the classpath that Weblogic is using when running your application.

You will need to investigate how exactly Weblogic sets up the classpath, and make sure the version of the .jars you need are on the classpath before the preexisting version (unless that preexisting version is there by mistake, in which case you can just remove the preexisting one from the classpath).