# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Bouncy Castle and Apache Spark

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, jar, bouncycastle

I actually found a company (where I work) specific work-around this issue, but the problem is so bizarre, I wanted to see if anyone else has ran into this issue and how they solved it.

First I added two bouncy castle dependencies to my spark job:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcpg-jdk15on -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.52</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also have this plugin to create a jar with all dependencies:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.theclasspath.jobs.TestingJob</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

So all the dependencies are getting installed. Now this will compile and create the jar. When I run spark-submit with the jar with dependencies, I get a no such method error for some methods in the org.bouncycastle.util package. The main one being:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.util.Strings.newList()Lorg/bouncycastle/util/StringList;
```

when trying to just run `Strings.newList();` in the main class. So I ran `mvn dependency:tree` to see if there were multiple versions of bouncy castle, and I only saw the dependencies I added to the pom.

Here is the really weird part: if I build the jar and run it with `java -jar jar-name-jar-with-dependencies.jar` (meaning not through spark-submit) the dependency gets added just fine, and I do not see any errors. So with that in mind, what would be the differences between the spark submit jar and just running the jar directly?
Why would one work and the other fail? I have tried running it on different machines, such as an emr job, and I still see the same error. (and to avoid this getting asked, I am using the jar-with-dependencies jar for the spark job)

One final note, I have seen this post [Bouncy castle no such method error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529351/bouncy-castle-no-such-method-error), and it doesn't apply, since I can get the jar to run when I just run the jar by itself without spark-submit.

Comment: I know very little about spark, but it seems obvious that the node you have submitted the job to is providing a conflicting (pre-1.52) version of BC into your runtime classpath. e.g. it is very typical to install the BC provider jar into the jre/lib/ext directory of a jvm. Perhaps there are other more spark-specific mechanisms that also provide pre-installed jars, I don't know. Actually the situation is probably very close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529351/bouncy-castle-no-such-method-error, and the reasoning you gave to dismiss it is backwards IMO.

Comment: Also, if you have any influence over the version of BC being used, please urge an upgrade to the latest (1.56) and ongoing regular updates to our new releases.